# Java Print Stream printing spaces

Tags: java, csv, printstream

I'm trying to print out a collection of words to a CSV file and am trying to avoid spaces being printed as a word.

```
    static TreeMap<String,Integer> wordHash = new TreeMap<String,Integer>();
    Set words=wordHash.entrySet();
    Iterator it = words.iterator();

      while(it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        System.out.println(me.getKey() + " occured " + me.getValue() + " times");
        if (!me.getKey().equals(" ")) {
        ps.println(me.getKey() + "," + me.getValue());
        }
    }
```

Whenever I open the CSV, as well as in the console, the output is :

```
        1
  10    1
   a    4
test    2
```

I am trying to remove that top entry of a space, I thought the statement checking if the key wasn't a space would work however it's still printing spaces. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: try `String#trim()` on your key and value

Comment: We can't know what it is. It could be two spaces, three spaces, a tab, a non-breaking space, etc. Use your debugger and see by yourself. Or open the file with a text editor and see by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition will eliminate only single space keys. If you want to eliminate any number of empty spaces, use :

```
if (!me.getKey().trim().isEmpty()) {
    ...
}
```

This is assuming `me.getKey()` can't be null.